# Why do some musicians play and sing on the streets?

Tags: careers

I am not sure if this a workplace question. But, this question is related to careers.

I see a lot of musicians playing and singing on the streets. Some of them seem to be very competent in their instruments.

- [AMAZING Street Performers singing stunning covers and great original music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfKs3ProM7M)

Why don't they get professionally hired?

Comment: Perhaps they are professionals and just busking for instant feedback/enjoyment instead of waiting the 3 months practicing for the next large opera which will be delayed again due to lockdown.

Comment: This is one of those questions for which there are hundreds of possible answers but they boil down to one of three: they don't want to, they do want to but can't, or they have and busk anyway.

Comment: @BSMP To add to that, they busk in order to promote their professional careers by having CDs available for sale.

Comment: How much do they earn doing this?

Answer (score 7):

A lot are transient or music students. The reasons they do it are anything from 'for fun' to making some quick and maybe even serious cash. And a busker in the right place at the right time who can engage an audience can easily walk away $500 richer after a few hours. Some people have no ambition to do more.

A band costs money, venues cost money, recording and editing costs money. Busking just requires an instrument and time.

Comment: Busking might also require a permit depending on the city.

Comment: @xander sure if you're a pro busker, but otherwise you just move along whenever authority tells you to and you usually get a golden sympathy handshake from onlookers who were enjoying your performance on the way

Answer (score 5):

Some do get hired.

It's actually a pretty good way to get exposure (mileage varies in these strange times...).  But as a semi-professional with a fair knowledge of fellow performers who do this, I can tell you that busking is actually a not-terrible way to make money as a performer if your art fits that format, and you have both the talent and the charisma to pull it off.  In some areas, it's also legislated (as in you need to get a permit) - which means that you also have to have your act together enough to get and maintain a permit.

Reasons to do it include:

- The practice - as opposed to a booked show at a gig that wants you around for somewhere between minutes and a couple of hours most of the time - busking is something you can do fairly regularly, and for longer intervals and you can repeat material fairly easily.  Practice is how you get from good enough to great.  And practice in front of a crowd is a separate way of developing mastery from practice by yourself.  The buskers I know are one and all VERY good at handling crowds and interacting with the public - a skill that is NOT universal across all performers in all venues.
- All gigs are hard to come by and precious - especially if you are interested in staying fixed in an area, there are a very finite number of jobs for performers that will make you any money.  This is one of them.  I would be really surprised to find a major city with a thriving tourist area that that DOESN'T have more talented performers than jobs for them.  If you know of this city, please post in comments, I have some friends that will move there. :)
- It gets your name out there.  I don't know of any fellow performers who got "discovered" specifically by busking, but I know a few folks who got a break and played TV (usually competition shows) at the same time that they were busking.  The sad truth about the big time high profile opportunities, is that they are also even harder to come by than in-town gigs.  As such, for the folks who provide such opportunities - it's not about finding raw talent, it's about sorting through all the people who want the opportunity to find the most promising.
- It is a reasonably flexible job, compared to a booked gig.  If you are working a special event, or an evening performance - you have some pretty specific demands on your time - they will want you to show up at a certain time, perform at a certain time, and possibly even [customize][1] your performance to that venue .  You have both more schedule freedom, and freedom in choosing your material --- [somewhat][2]  --- for the cost of having to plan out and provide all your own [logistics.][3]
- Some material just plays better in this format.  And/or it's not mainstream enough to make it as a major production.  Sometimes (rarely) that gets disproven when some cool street show becomes mainstream via YouTube or TV competitions.  But it can be hard to get that going w/out spending time in a street venue.  Sadly - even for a mainstream band, doing the first album with a major label is usually something that does NOT make a profit.  A band has to make several hit albums to be in the black, financially - or that's how it used to be.  Happily - YouTube, streaming music, and other online distribution channels are disrupting that a whole lot - but there's still an art to the business and you don't really make it big until you come up with something that appeals to a whole LOT of people.  It's a really competitive industry.

[1]: ... and don't get me going on what it's like to try to arrange a private performance with customers who have no idea what it requires to perform that art.  Picture people putting on giant costumes in a space the size of a garbage can.  Picture people wanting you to perform with flaming equipment next to a bale of hay...  the list goes on...

[2]:  While you can do almost anything that isn't offensive, dangerous or terribly annoying (or off the allowed hours) when busking, most buskers learn material that works and material that doesn't.  If you want to make money, you do what works, which isn't necessarily your favorite material.

[3]:  By logistics, I mean most street gigs don't give you any equipment - you bring the chair, the mic, the amp, an extension chord, a tip jar and whatever else you need.  In contrast, in a music hall, you can expect chairs, mic stands, sometimes mics, speakers, etc - all to be provided by the venue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one right answer of course but I’ve spoken to some who say the amount of money they earn from tips playing on the street can be comparable to or sometimes even exceed what they would earn playing in a venue.

Some do it just for fun or to see what sort of reaction they get, such as world renowned violinist Joshua Bell:
https://www.pbs.org/newshour/arts/grammy-winning-violinist-joshua-bell-takes-another-turn-at-a-subway-concert